# invalid Queue letter

Tags: c, struct

Currently I am very confused as I am not sure if I am understanding my task correctly. My understanding was that I have to create queues with each having a list of a certain amount of messages within them. Am I wrong? As I feel that i'm slipping into nothing. Have i got the wrong idea what a queue is? Should i be creating one queue? What exactly should i be doing?

```
/* Restores a queue previously stored by persistQ() back to memory as identified by its filename.
   The queue identifier is automatically taken from the filename.
   Returns an error if the filename does not exist or the queue id has been already taken. */
//restoreQ(){}


int main(){
    char choice, *msg, *q;

    printf("\n1 - Create a queue");
    printf("\n2 - List queues");
    printf("\n3 - Delete a queue");
    printf("\n4 - Send a message");
    printf("\n5 - Receive a message");
    printf("\n6 - Purge queue/s (If not specified, all queues will be cleared)");
    printf("\n7 - Persist a queue");
    printf("\n8 - Restore a queue");

    //createQ();

    while(1){
        printf("\nEnter choice: ");
        scanf(" %c", &choice);
        switch(choice){
            case '1':
                printf("Enter queue name");
                createQ(msg_queue_t -> qName);
            case '4':
                printf("Enter queue name:");
                scanf("%s", &q);
                printf("Enter message:");
                scanf("%s", &msg);
                sendMessage(q, msg);
                break;
            default:
                printf("Incorrrect, Re-try");
                break;
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: ```MsgQs_t``` must contain an array of message queues and each message queue contains: an id so you can identify it and a queue for the messages

Comment: Please do not vandalise your title.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, you got the idea right of what a queue is. It tells you that `MsgQs_t` contains a number of message queues and each message queue contains a queue and an identifier (ID). The structure of the code would look something like this

```
#define MSG_BUF_LEN (some_size)

/* number of message queues */
#define MSGQS_LEN   (some_size)

/* number of nodes in the message queue */
#define NMESSAGES   (some_size)

typedef struct _node {

    int8_t        message[MSG_BUF_LEN];

    struct _node *next;

} node_t;

typedef struct {

    int32_t id;

    node_t *first_message;

    node_t *last_message;

} msg_queue_t;


typedef struct {

    msg_queue_t **queues;

}MsgQs_t;



/* Returns a pointer to MsgQs_t structure and through which multiple message queues can be subsequently created.
   Each individual message queue is to be identified by a unique identifier. */
MsgQs_t * init_msgq(){

    MsgQs_t *msg_queues;

    msg_queues = malloc(sizeof(MsgQs_t));

    if(msg_queues < 0)
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);

    return(msg_queues);
}
```

You still have to implement the other functions that help you initialize the message queues as well as adding a message into a specific message queue--you'd have to pass as argument an identifier and the message.

==========================================================================

Going through your code there are major problems and I would advise you to learn how memory allocation works in C as well as pointers.

```
/* Relinquishes all resources currently held by a MsgQs_t.
   The pointer to the MsgQs_t in question is set to NULL. */
MsgQs_t * unloadMsgQs(){
    MsgQs_t *msg_queues;
    msg_queues = NULL;

    return(msg_queues);
}
```

Just by setting the pointer to `NULL` will not release the memory. What you have It's called a *memory leak*, as `malloc` still has that chunk of memory as occupied but you have lost the reference to it. Also, you have to release the memory of the address that was returned by the function `init_msgqs` and don't forget that you also have to release the memory of Its members as It won't do it recursively by itself

```
struct _node* newNode(const char *m){
    struct _node* temp = (struct _node*)malloc(sizeof(struct _node*));
    temp -> message = m;
    temp -> next = NULL;
    return temp;
}
```

`sizeof(struct _node*)` will return you the size of a pointer instead of the size of the structure itself. Please learn what is the difference between `sizeof(struct _node)` and `sizeof(struct _node*)` as It's important.

The rest of the code will not work as well. Since this is not the code review community, I will stop here and suggest you to familiarize yourself with pointers and how they work before proceeding any further.

Comment: @NathanCamilleri It's equivalent to ```char message[size]``` - ```int8_t``` is a fixed width data type(https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/C_Programming/stdint.h)

Comment: intn_t are fixed width - read what I sent you. N tells you the bits the data type contains, so int32_t has 32 bits, 32/8 = 4 bytes

Comment: @NathanCamilleri could you please edit your question and add the code there as It's a bit difficult to follow.